# Naudio Buffer Full Exception in Naudio library while i am playing audio from byte array of .wav file

Tags: exception, buffer, naudio

> Its work fine when i set delay 20 but wav file playing slowly in some systems with windows 10.

```
private static void waveSourceAgent_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        int delay = 10; 
        recordedMsgBuffer = RECORDING_BUFFER[0].recordedMsgBuffer;
        int iterations = recordedMsgBuffer.Length / 320;
        int remainingBytes = recordedMsgBuffer.Length % 320;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[320];
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            byte[] tempbuff = new byte[320];
            for (int j = 0; j < 320; j++)
            {
                tempbuff[j] = recordedMsgBuffer[(i * 320) + j];
            }
            if (waveProviderReciever != null)
                waveProviderReciever.AddSamples(tempbuff, 0, tempbuff.Length);
            Thread.Sleep(delay);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to play data that's being received (but not sure exactly how - you're not using the `DataAvailable` args) by putting it into a `BufferedWaveProvider`.

The secret to this working is that the speed at which audio is being placed into the buffer should match the speed it is being read out. If the `WaveFormat` of record and playback match (which they need to for this to work) then the buffer should never fill up unless playback has unexpectedly stopped.

If you are receiving data much faster than you are playing it (e.g. you are downloading a pre-recorded audio file), then you either need to increase the buffer size, or hold off putting any new data into the buffer until there is more space available.

Comment: but its working in mostly systems and only few systems with windows 10 can't play audio file properly voice is playing slowly.

Comment: you need to look at the WaveFormats then. They likely don't match if audio is playing slowly

Comment: Let me explain you the scenario :-
# its working in windows 7 perfectly.
# If the Wave Format working in windows 7 then it should be working in windows 10 also.
#  Wave Format that we are using is perfect and what could be the reason for not working in few windows 10 pc/laptop where as we tried to set the delay 10 mili-second.
# When delay set to 10 then we are facing buffer full exception error that is what we want the solution for that.
# If we set the delay 20 then recording is playing but slowly.